# React and css for radio and label

Tags: html, css, reactjs, less

I hate css, I really do. I think this one will be trivial for most of you so please help me with this one. 
I would like to create a radiobutton which have to change the background color of the label it's in. Here's the code which obviously does not work:
js:

```
<div className="container">
  <label className="check" htmlFor="id">
    <input {...radio.input} name="radio" type="radio" id="id" />
  </label>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.check {
background-color: green;
display: inline-block;
height: 34px;
position: relative;
width: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.check input {
display:none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + .check {
background-color: blue; 
}

.container {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` selector in CSS selects the next element in the HTML. Doing `input + label` is not going to work because your input is wrapped in the label.

The easiest solution for this would be to apply a `checked` CSS class in react when the input is checked. The other option would be to place the label AFTER the input in your markup, but that will probably require you to apply more CSS to get the appearance you need.

Answer (score 0):

I really love CSS, I really do! ;)

Change your HTML to:

```
<div className="container">
  <input {...radio.input} name="radio" type="radio" id="id" />
  <label className="check" htmlFor="id">
  </label>
</div>
```

and style the radio button individually.